# Centering and filling a div with an image without distortion

Tags: css, html, centering, stretching

I keep finding *almost* solutions to something that I feel should be really simple, but can't figure it out. (note - i'm at a really rudimentary stage of learning CSS right now)

I have one image to put on a page. Center horizontal/vertical. In a `div` container that is 80% of the window height and width. I would like the image to stretch to fill either the height or the width of that `div`, based on whichever is smallest.

I'm sure this is simple for most, but again, I'm just learning. Any direction on this would be wonderful.

I created an illustration in case i'm not explaining well enough:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/ddh2k/

This does most of what you want. You'll need to add some extra javascript if you really only want the image to be 80% of the available height when the screen height is reduced to less than the image intrinsic height.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg" alt="apropriate alt text">
</div>
</body>

html,
body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #eee;
}
#container{
    margin: auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background:#aae;
}
#container:before{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
img {
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: this is similar to what i'd already been trying, with no luck in getting the image to center vertically.  i tinkered with what you offered, and still get pretty much the same result. the page i've been testing on is at http://modnpop.com/test/